# popover in the footer

Tags: css, sapui5

I am using an icon in the footer using fragmentation. On press of the icon, it opens a popover. I want the popover above the footer but it is opening below it and no content is visible.

sapui5 `<xml>`

```
<footer>
    <OverflowToolbar id="otbFooter">
        <ToolbarSpacer/>
        <OverflowToolbarButton text="Add" icon="sap-icon://add" press="popover" class="popover"/>
    </OverflowToolbar>
</footer>
```

[image: screen shot of popover I expect]

Answer (score 1):

Set [`placement`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Popover.html#getPlacement) property of `sap.m.Popover` to `Top`.

```
<Popover title="{Name}" placement="Top">
```